# Why doesn't the person that the narrator is waiting for show up in this poem by Hemirah Tohti?

Tags: poetry, uyghur-language, drops-of-melodies, hemirah-tohti

The poem *You said you will come* by Hemirah Tohti (from *Drops of Melodies*) reads as follows:

> You sent the news that you were coming
> I wake up full of joy in the morning
> Many years have passed
> My eyes never stop looking
> To the direction you arrive
> Many spring pased now
> You wanted to come but couldn't
> Days can pass - I can wait
> But age can pass, it cannot return
> I cry, I yearn But I understand
> Your strife
> I know - this is the way
> Of life, I passed that road
> If you can't come - just let me know
> The news of how you are
> As long as your [sic] are healthy
> My preyers [sic] with [sic] reach you

Are we given any clues as to exactly why the other person didn't show up? Is this poem referring to someone who was forcibly disappeared, or are there other explanations here? Or is this poem along the similar line as *Waiting for Godot* in the sense that the narrator is indefinitely waiting for someone who never shows up?

Comment: Is this some homework?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, it's part of this month's [reading challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/announcing-the-march-april-2024-topic-challenge-uyghur-literature).